# Explain: Math.fround() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, math

### How do works `Math.fround()` function.

> The `Math.fround()` function returns the nearest float representation of a number.

But when it is passed the float number `Math.fround(1.5)`  it returns the same(1.5) value.
But when it is passed the float number `Math.fround(1.55)` it returns a different value `1.5499999523162841`. **why and How?**

> - I am confused about how `Math.fround()` works.
> - How is it different from the `Math.round()` function?
> - Also let me know why it's not supported in `Internet Explorer`.

Comment: you can start your understanding with [JavaScript’s Number type in details](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/javascripts-number-type-8d59199db1b6)

Comment: Did you read about single-precision? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I couldn't see that page :(

Comment: write the number in binary and you will understand. 1.5 is `2^0 +  2^-1` but 1.55 can not be represented as sum of powers of 2 so it is like iracional number for binary representation ...  that is why you got so many diigtis ...

Comment: *fround* is not supported by IE, but MDN has a [*pollyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/fround#Polyfill).

Comment: @RobG it's funny, but their polyfill doesn't work on compliant browsers since they don't construct `Float32Array` with `new`..

Comment: @PatrickRoberts—you can fix it if you like, MDN is a public wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand how this function works you actually have to know the following topics:

- [JavaScript’s Number type in details](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/javascripts-number-type-8d59199db1b6)
- [The simple math behind decimal-binary conversion algorithms](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/the-simple-math-behind-decimal-binary-conversion-algorithms-d30c967c9724)
- [How to round binary numbers](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/how-to-round-binary-fractions-625c8fa3a1af)
- [The mechanics behind exponent bias in floating point](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/the-mechanics-behind-exponent-bias-in-floating-point-9b3185083528)

The ECMA script specifies [the following algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-math.fround) for the conversion:

> When Math.fround is called with argument x, the following steps are
>   taken:
>
> - If x is NaN, return NaN.
> - If x is one of +0, -0, +∞, -∞, return x.
> - Let x32 be the result of converting x to a value in IEEE 754-2008 binary32
>     format using roundTiesToEven.
> - Let x64 be the result of converting x32
>     to a value in IEEE 754-2008 binary64 format.
> - Return the ECMAScript
>     Number value corresponding to x64.

So, let's do that for `1.5` and `1.55`.

#### Math.fround(1.5)

1) Represent in 64bit float

```
0 01111111111 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

2) Represent in the scientific notation

```
1.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 x 2^0
```

3) Round to 23 bit mantissa

```
1.10000000000000000000000
```

4) Convert to decimal:

```
1.5
```

#### Math.fround(1.55)

1) Represent in 64bit float

```
0 01111111111 1000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

2) Represent in the scientific notation

```
1.1000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 x 2^0
```

3) Round to 23 bit mantissa

```
1.10001100110011001100110
```

4) Convert to decimal:

```
1.5499999523162841
```

Comment: Nice explanation dude +1

Comment: @RameshRajendran, consider accepting then if it helped)

Answer (score 0):

> **I got these below things which is I got from some of the documents. Kindly share your answers if you have more details.**

---

I have found something about `Math.fround ( x )` from [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.fround)

When `Math.fround()` is called with argument x the following steps are taken:

- If x is NaN, return NaN.
- If x is one of +0, −0, +∞, −∞, return x.
- Let x32 be the result of converting x to a value in IEEE 754-2008 binary32 format using roundTiesToEven.
- Let x64 be the result of converting x32 to a value in IEEE 754-2008 binary64 format.
- Return the ECMAScript Number value corresponding to x64.

---

This can be emulated with the following function, if [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) are supported:

```
Math.fround = Math.fround || (function (array) {
  return function(x) {
    return array[0] = x, array[0];
  };
})(Float32Array(1));
```

---

** ***Kindly share more answers for learning more details***